# Subset dask dataframe by column position

Tags: python, pandas, dask

Once I have a dask dataframe, how can I selectively pull columns into an in-memory pandas DataFrame? Say I have an N x M dataframe. How can I create an N x m dataframe where m << M and is arbitrary.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import dask.dataframe as dd

d = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(d.data)
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, chunksize=100)
```

#### What I would like to do:

```
in_memory = ddf.iloc[:,2:4].compute()
```

#### What I have been able to do:

```
ddf.map_partitions(lambda x: x.iloc[:,2:4]).compute()
```

`map_partitions` works but it was quite slow on a file that wasn't very large. I hope I am missing something very obvious.

Comment: It is useful to you to simply get the columns (`cols = list(ddf.columns[2:4])`) and index by them (`ddf[cols]`)?

Comment: That does it! And it's a lot faster than what I attempted. Please add as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although iloc is not implemented for dask-dataframes, you can achieve the indexing easily enough as follows:

```
cols = list(ddf.columns[2:4])
ddf[cols].compute()
```

This has the additional benefit, that dask knows immediately the types of the columns selected, and needs to do no additional work. For the `map_partitions` variant, dask at the least needs to check the data types produces, since the function you call is completely arbitrary.